# Loading data into grid from Form Panel response

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a form with an associated grid catering to one to many relationship.
When I load the form using url then I also get the grid data using the following code

```
this.load({
        url:reportURL + 'editReport',
        waitMsg:'Loading...',
        params:{
            reportIdKey: this.reportId
        },
        success:function(form,action){                
            response = action.result.data; // Contains the data for the grid               
        }
    })
```

The returned json is as follows

```
{
"data":{
  "setupDt":"09-27-2011",
  "expireDt":"12-31-1950",
  "reportNm":"Report_55283",
  "templateNm":"risk_measures_tmpl",
  "GridData":
  *[
     {
        "sId":1,
        "sNm":"W",
        "mId":1,
        "mNm":"R",
        "pId":"..",
        "pIdAlias":"",
        "bId":"...",
        "bIdAlias":"",
        "pDesc":"FUND==GB|ACT==WG|W",
        "grpId":"",
        "scF":"",
        "sortSeq":1,
        "grpN":1
     }
  ]*
```

how can I load the grid data from the above json into my grid.

Please help..
    },
    "success":"true"
    }

Comment: `*[` and `]*` in JSON ? I would remove them, and what you doing with response ?

Comment: Actually I was trying to make it into italics. Please ignore.. I have the response with me but I don't know how to add it to store of the grid

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS grids use a store to update the grid. The store is in fact required. You can just use a [json store](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore). When you get call `loadData` against the store when you get the response. The reason you would use `loadData` instead of `load`, is because the form has already done the AJAX call, and `load` would try to make it again. For example (this all assumes ExtJS 3.4, I don't know what version you are using, but it's pretty much the same thing in ExtJS 4):

```
    var gridStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        root: 'GridData',
        fields: [
            'sid',
            // ... your other field names under 'GridData'
        ]
    });
    var myGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: gridStore,
        // ... your other config options here
    });
    this.load({
        url:reportURL + 'editReport',
        waitMsg:'Loading...',
        params:{
            reportIdKey: this.reportId
        },
        success:function(form,action){                
            response = action.result.data; // Contains the data for the grid
            gridStore.loadData(response);
        }
    });
```

Once `loadData` completes, the grid will automatically update itself as part of the normal `load` event handlers that are attached to the store by the grid when you construct the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around by iterating over the result json and setting the corresponding property in the store.getRecordType({field:value}).